# how to trigger a Azure Synapse pipeline only when the other two Synapse pipelines have completed successfully

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, orchestration

I want  to trigger a Azure Synapse pipeline only when the other two Synapse pipelines have completed successfully.  how we can do that in a simple way?

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried and if you are getting any error?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet.Looking for ideas/samples.

Comment: You can [Create a tumbling window trigger dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tumbling-window-trigger-dependency?ocid=AID754288&wt.mc_id=CFID0477) to make your pipelines dependent on each other.

Answer (score 0):

The most easy would be to add a copy activity at the end of each pipeline (the initial 2 pipelines) to upload a file in blob location.
Create an storage event trigger on the 3rd pipeline which would trigger on arrival of files.
Use get meta data activity to check for existence of 2 files in blob for the 3rd pipeline activities to proceed further else ignore the event trigger.
My blog for reference:
https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2022/09/24/event-trigger-of-synapse-azure-data-factory-pipeline-on-arrival-of-nth-file-in-azure-blob-storage/
explains the end to end process